# return string from database

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to create a method in my Db. i want to return a string from my db in a specific row with a specific column name.
I've try this but it don't works.
Can someone help me please??

```
public String getNameAtPosition(String row){
    String name = null;

    Cursor c = mDb.query(ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_TABLE, null, ValuteMetaData.ID + "=" + row, null, null, null, null);

    name = String.valueOf(c.getLong(ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_NAME_KEY));

    return name;
}


public Cursor fetchValuteListView(String data){ 
        String[] data_query={data};
        return mDb.query(ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_TABLE,null,ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_DATA_KEY+"=?",data_query,null,null,null);              
}


static class ValuteMetaData {  // i metadati della tabella, accessibili ovunque
        static final String VALUTE_TABLE = "Valute";
        static final String ID = "_id";
        static final String VALUTE_NAME_KEY = "name";
        static final String VALUTE_SIGLA_KEY = "sigla";
        static final String VALUTE_CAMBIO_KEY = "cambio";
        static final String VALUTE_DATA_KEY = " data";
}

private static final String VALUTE_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "  //codice sql di creazione della tabella
                + ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_TABLE + " ("
                + ValuteMetaData.ID+ " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_NAME_KEY + " text, "
                + ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_SIGLA_KEY + " text, "
                + ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_CAMBIO_KEY + " text, "
                + ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_DATA_KEY + " text);";
```

Comment: i don't have error. i need help to improve my code in the method "public String getNameAtPosition" for return a string with the record selected

Answer (score 1):

Change your method and query as below:

```
public String getNameAtPosition(String row){
    String name = null;

    Cursor c = mDb.query(ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_TABLE, null,
            ValuteMetaData.ID + " = ?" , new String[]{row}, null, null, null);

    if(c.moveToFirst())
        name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_NAME_KEY));

    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before using Cursor you should point it to the row. In your case you should write:

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
name = String.valueOf(c.getLong(ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_NAME_KEY));
```

to  (pay attention to "getString" and "getColumnIndex")

```
if(c.moveToFirst()){
    name = String.valueOf(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_NAME_KEY)));
}
```